# The cardinality of elliptic curves over finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Given an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$ as $y^2=f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial.

In some places I read that if $p$ is a prime of good reduction then we have that $E(\mathbb F_p)=p+1$. Is this really true? If yes, why? Is there a (if possible simple) explanation? If it's not true in general, then what are the conditions?

I only know that we have $E(\mathbb F_p)\leq2p+1$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is "a prime of good reduction"?

Comment: Moreover, [Hasse-Weil's bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves) gives $E(\mathbb{F}_p)\leq p+1+2\sqrt{p}$.

Comment: It's when you have *bad* reduction (specifically, "additive reduction") that you get $p+1$. See, e.g., http://mathoverflow.net/questions/98466/how-many-points-are-there-on-an-elliptic-curve-reduced-at-a-bad-prime

Answer (score 3):

That is false in general. For example if $E\colon y^2=x^3+x+1$, then $E(\mathbb F_5)=9$.

It is true that if $p>2$ is a prime of good supersingular reduction, then the trace of the Frobenius at $p$ is $0$, so that $E(\mathbb F_p)=p+1$.

Comment: Okay. And why this is true? Is there any reference for this statement?

Comment: Sure, for example Silverman's "The arithmetic of elliptic curves" Theorem V.4.1

Comment: Also proved this in my answer below, for the curious reader who is without a copy of Silverman.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Ferra's answer. This is a true statement for $p > 3$ a prime of supersingular reduction, i.e. one for which the endomorphism ring is an order in a quaternion algebra. This is because we have that if $\phi_p$ is frobenius then we know that:

$ [|{E(\mathbb{F}_p)}|] = [\text{deg}(1 - \phi_p)] = (1 - \phi_p)(1 - \widehat{\phi}_p) = [1] + [\text{deg}(\phi_p)] - [\text{Tr}(\phi_p)]$

And

$\widehat{\phi_p} = [\text{Tr}(\phi_p)] - \phi_p$ is inseparable because our elliptic curve is supersingular, thus we know that $p | \text{Tr}(\phi_p)$ as the only inseparable isogenies of the form $[n], n \in \mathbb{Z}$ are those where $n = 0$ mod $p$. But by Hasse's estimate we have that $|\text{Tr}(\phi_p)| \leq 2\sqrt{p}$ and thus we have $np \leq 2\sqrt{p}$ and so for $p \neq 2,3$ we have $n = 0$ and thus $[|{E(\mathbb{F}_p)}|] = [1] + [\text{deg}(\phi_p)] = [1 + p]$ and so we are done.

Comment: In fact $n = 1$ and $p = 3$  is also possible, and so $a_3$ needn't equal zero.  You could add that it really needn't be true that $a_2 = 0$ or that $a_3 = 0$ in the s.s. case.  E.g. $X_0(11)$ has good s.s. reduction mod $2$, and has $a_2 = -2$, while [Cremona's tables](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgaj/ftp/data/) show an elliptic curve of conductor 26 with $a_3 = -3$.  (Look at table 3.)

Comment: True, I wasn't really calculating clearly in my head this morning. I've edited it to make it correct.